# Java - Commons-fileupload.jar - Problem

Tags: java, file-upload, struts

I am trying to upload a file using `commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar` file (I know it is not the latest version but it comes with `struts 1.3.10` so I am using the same).

Now the problem is when I parse the `request` (HttpServletRequest) to get a `List` of `FileItem`s, I am getting an empty list.

```
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        File tempDir = new File("/fileUploadDirectory");
        tempDir.mkdir();

        // Set factory constraints
        factory.setSizeThreshold(10000);
        factory.setRepository(tempDir);

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        // Set overall request size constraint
        upload.setSizeMax(10000);

        // Parse the request
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        System.out.println(items);

        System.out.println(request.getContentLength());

        // Process the uploaded items
        Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = iter.next();
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                System.out.println("File is a FormField");
            } else {
                System.out.println("File is a File");
            }
        }
```

Q1. Why I am getting an empty list?

When I am printing the size of the request by `request.getContentLength()` (as shown above in the code), I get some numerical data (1536) which I think is showing the length of the file. If it is showing the length of the file, then why I am not getting list of `FileItem`s?

**Note:** I am using it with `Struts 1.3.10` with `ActionForm`. Is is creating any problem.

**Note:** I am also not getting any exception while parsing the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is empty, then the request was most likely not send as `multipart/form-data`. Ensure that the request method is set to `post` and that encoding type is set to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

(just substitute the HTML `<form>` element with the Struts equivalent, which is likely `<html:form>`)

That said, why don't you make use of the Struts builtin file upload component? [Googling](http://google.com/search?q=struts+file+upload) learns me that there's a `<html:file>` component which needs to be tied with a `org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile` property.

Comment: I was using both `multipart/form-data` and `post`. I tried Struts built-in file upload component too. It also didn't work because I was using `<form>` tag of HTML. When I tried `<html:file>`, the problem solved... I don't know why `struts` doesn't support `<form>`.. it's strange... but anyway thanks...

Comment: It's not strange. If you don't use the framework-provided components, it won't be able to properly associate the request with a specific action and model.